# On the definition of the Atiyah class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I am reading the book *Complex Geometry: an Introduction* by Daniel Huybrechts. On page 180 the author defined the Atiyah class as follows:

> The Atiyah class $$A(E)\in H^1(X,\Omega_X\otimes \mathrm{End}(E))$$ of the holomorphic vector bundle E is given by the $\mathrm{\check{C}}$ech cocycle
> $$A(E)=\{U_{ij},\psi_j^{-1}\circ(\psi_{ij}^{-1}d\psi_{ij})\circ\psi_j\}.$$

Here $X$ is a complex manifold and $X=\cup U_i$ is an open covering such that $\psi_i\colon E|_{U_i}\cong U_i\times\mathbb{C}^r$ are holomorphic trivializations, and $\Omega_X$ is the sheaf of holomorphic 1-forms on $X$. Moreover, $U_{ij}:=U_i\cap U_j.$

I cannot see why these $\psi_j^{-1}\circ(\psi_{ij}^{-1}d\psi_{ij})\circ\psi_j$ are in sections $\Gamma(U_{ij}, \Omega_X\otimes \mathrm{End}(E)).$ If this is true, take some $x\in U_{ij},$ $v\in T_xX$ and $e\in\Gamma(U_{ij},E),$ then $v\otimes e(x)$ should be mapped by $\psi_j^{-1}\circ(\psi_{ij}^{-1}d\psi_{ij})\circ\psi_j(x)$ to an element in $\mathbb{C}\otimes E.$ But I think the result should still be in $T_xX\otimes E,$ as $d\psi_{ij}$ is from $T(U_{ij}\times\mathbb{C}^r)$ to $T(U_{ij}\times\mathbb{C}^r)$. Where am I wrong? Could someone help me?

Comment: Take a look at the proof of proposition 4.2.19, $d\psi_{ij}$ is not the differential of $\psi_{ij}$. Here in this context, $d$ and $\psi_{ij}$ are two operators, you can think of a section as vector-valued functions, and $\psi_{ij}$ as matrix multiplying on the vector, and $d$ as the taking the differential at every entry, i.e. $d(s_1,...,s_n)=(ds_1,...,ds_n)$.

Comment: @yzhou - There is an exact sequence (the Atiyah sequence) $0 \rightarrow \Omega^1 \otimes E \rightarrow J^1(E) \rightarrow E \rightarrow 0$ giving a class $at(E) \in Ext^1_{\mathcal{O}_X}(E, \Omega^1 \otimes E) \cong H^1(X, \Omega^1\otimes End(E))$.

Comment: @lEm I think the first line of the proof of prop. 4.2.19 shows that $d$ does mean differential here.

Comment: @yzhou You are right, sorry for the mistake. I think $d\psi_{ij}$ is a map from $TU_{ij}$ to $M_{r\times r}(\mathbb C)$, because the author is taking $\psi_{ij}: U_{ij}\to GL(r,\mathbb C)$.

Comment: @lEm I think your latter explanation really makes sense. Thanks for your insight.